# calculator ignore value text when submitting

Tags: javascript, textbox, calculator

I'm putting together a calculator in Javascript and my text fields have value text in their boxes to indicate the size of a can (ml). Since there's more than 10 text fields with text in them, not all of them will be utilized when people use the calculator. I was wondering how i can convert the text field boxes to represent 0 when a submit button is pressed,otherwise the total box shows "isNaN" when submitted,because i have code that states the text fields to return a message when letters are in the text fields while the submit button is pressed.

```
if (isNaN(smallCanIn || mediumCanIn || largeCanIn)){
        alert("Please enter a number value");
    }
```

i've tried creating a variable with string data that represents the text shown in the text field (value text in the text field is "0-300 ml") 
var smallCanUnclicked="0-300 ml";
but nothing seems to work. Please help. Thank you

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to check if a valid entry has been entered, or how to convert `smallCanUnclicked` into an integer?

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and/or clarify on what exactly you're asking.

Comment: each text box has value text but each text box might not be used in the calculator. My question is: How do I make the value text convert to "0" when a submit button is pressed to calculate number figures?